# Redundant L2 Uplink (OS10)

Tags: networking, switch, dell, redundancy, etherchannel

I am trying to design a redundant uplink to a service provider from a pair of Dell S4112 switches running OS10. We a getting two uplink connections from the service provider, but they cannot be delivered as an LACP trunk.

Our switch pair is providing redundant connections to our internal network using a mix of static and LACP trunks using VLT, and it is working perfectly.

I realize this problem could be solved by placing the edge routers in a VRRP cluster in front of the switches, each with a direct connection to the service provider. However, I would like an L2 solution to achieve cross-redundancy. I.e., they can have a link down while we have ongoing maintenance on a router.

I hope to avoid having to revert to some form of spanning-tree solution because I have no control over the vendors and firmware at the service provider.

I had hoped to find an active/passive mode for a port channel with VLT on the switches, but I have been unable to find such a feature in the documentation. Have I missed something, or is there another feature available that might solve the problem?

I hope I have explained the problem clearly, and I look forward to hearing suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

That highly depends on how your ISP configured the redundant uplink.

VRRP (virtual gateway IP failing over from one port to the other): just connect both ports into the same segment/VLAN. VRRP failover will take care of redirecting the traffic towards the VRRP gateway.

(Switched) static trunk (gateway responds to packets send to either port): should also be configured as a static (=non-LACP) LAG trunk.

Two (clustered) gateway IPs: need to be configured independently with some kind of your own failover scheme. Can be combined with OSPF or similar or requires monitoring/SLA.